# How to get javascript tooltip message in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to get a tool tip message which appear when mouse hover over an icon. I want to get the message in Selenium `gettext()` method and assign it to a `String`.

Below is my code:

```
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   String script = "return driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepository.tooltipMsg)).getText();";
   String message = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   System.out.println("message "+message);
```

This is not working and I'm getting the error `driver is not defined`

Comment: can you post the HTML code also...

Answer (score 2):

Error `driver is not defined` is thrown because of the below statement.

```
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepository.tooltipMsg)).getText();
```

This is actually not a Javascript, but a Java code to find the text of the webelement. Hence, driver defined in java cannot be used as such while creating a javascript.

Using Javascript:

```
String script = "return document.getElementById("your-id").innerHTML;";   
String message = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
```

Using Java:

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your XPath")).getText();
```

You need to provide the correct XPath or Id above to find the element. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I changed my code like this   String script = "return document.getElementById(\"_iwarn_txtNoOfNights\").innerHTML;";  But it prints a null value.

Comment: It may be printing `null` as text of tooltip is saved as title attribute. Try using `document.getElementById(\"_iwarn_txtNoOfNights\").getAttribute("title");`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

first, you need define your drvier:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

later, you can get attribute of element has tooltip

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ObjectRepository.tooltipMsg")).getAttribute("title");
```